# Writing byte data to directory

Tags: java

I try to write byte data to  directory I use the following code but i get this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\file (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
    at com.innvo.domain.App.main(App.java:17)
```

My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File dir = new File("C:\\file");
     if (dir.isDirectory())
     {
        String  x="new text string";
        File serverFile = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath());
       BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
             new FileOutputStream(serverFile));
       System.out.println(x.getBytes());
       stream.close();
   }else {
    System.out.println("not");
  }

     }
```

Comment: Looks like the user that executes the app doesn't have the right permissions to create the file. Try writing into a folder where you have such permissions.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [write byte data to directory (Access is denied)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28306367/write-byte-data-to-directory-access-is-denied) Do not create duplicates, especially if your previous question was already a duplicate.

Comment: Ok how fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

serverFile is a directory. FileOutputStream does not accept directories.
You cannot write to a directory like to a file.
Use something like  `

```
File serverFile = new File(dir,"mynewfile.txt");
```

Comment: Use `new File(dir, "mynewfile.txt")`.

Comment: @immibis: Thanks, i changed the answer.